# C# List to ICollection

Tags: c#

This is weird, I'm trying to initalize my ICollection with List in my constructor and this happens:

```
Schedules = new List<BookingSchedule>(); //OK
CateringItems = new List<CateringItem>(); //Not
```

The properties:

```
public virtual ICollection<BookingSchedule> Schedules { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<BookedCateringItem> CateringItems { get; set; }
```

Error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyApp.Models.CateringItem>' to  
'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MyApp.Models.BookedCateringItem>'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I can't see the difference between the two. I'm going insane trying to figure this out. Any idea?

Comment: You are trying to assign list of `BookedCateringItem` to collection of `CateringItem`. Types not match - that's the difference

Comment: What is BookedCateringItem? Try new List<BookedCateringItem>()

Comment: You need to read about `Covariance`. see http://tomasp.net/blog/variance-explained.aspx/

Comment: @haim770 I thought it's about compatibility of ICollection and List, I focused on that too much I ignored the type of the list I was trying to initialize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `CateringItems` is a collection of `BookedCateringItem`, while initializing, you initialized a list of `CateringItem`.

apparently they are not compatible...

Answer (score 19):

You can only convert `List<T1>` to `ICollection<T2>` if the types T1 and T2 are the same.
Alternatively, you can convert to the non-generic `ICollection`

```
ICollection CateringItems = new List<CateringItem>(); // OK
```

Comment: Done. And +1 for the extra suggestion about the non-generic `ICollection`, which in certain circumstances (WPF view-models) can be desirable.

Answer (score 4):

```
    public virtual ICollection<BookedCateringItem> CateringItems { get; set; }
    CateringItems = new List<CateringItem>();
```

It's different types, BookedCateringItem and CateringItem. You need to change one of them to be the other type.

Answer (score 0):

You want assign  `List<CateringItem>` to `ICollection<BookedCateringItem>` So you can not.